# Typescript typeguard error in class constructor

Tags: typescript

I have a class `BigNumber` whose constructor takes an initialising argument that can be either a string, number or a `BigNumber`. The constructor will initialise an instance of `BigNumber` using the appropriate strategy given the type of the argument:

```
export class BigNumber
{
     private static isDecimal = /^(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(e[+-]?\d+)?$/i;

     public d : number[];
     public e : number;
     public s : number;

     constructor(v : string | number | BigNumber)
     {
         let e, i, t,
             x = this;

         if (v instanceof BigNumber)
         {
              // code dependent of v being a BigNumber
              x.s = v.s;
              x.e = v.e;
              x.d = v.d.slice();
              return;
         }
         else if (typeof v === 'number')
         {
             // code dependent of v being a number

             if (v === 0)
             {
                x.s = (1 / v < 0) ? -1 : 1;
                x.e = 0;
                x.d = [0];
                return;
             }

             // Other stuff
         }
         else if(typeof v === 'string')
         {
             // code dependent of v being a string
             if (v.charCodeAt(0) === 45)
             {
                 v = v.slice(1);
                 x.s = -1;
             }
             else
             {
                 x.s = 1;
             }

             // Other stuff
         }
         else
         {
             // throw error
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is typescript kicks up a lot of errors relating to making assignments or calling functions like `slice()` in the string section i.e. typeguards are not working.

These can be fixed with explicit casts on each operation however I was under the impression that the typescript compiler was able to infer the type within a instanceOf or typeof block. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Your code has no errors, even when I add `console.log(v.slice(0, 3))` when it's a string I get no errors. Please provide the code that results in errors for you.

Comment: @NitzanTomer have added some additional code some it now gives some of the errors I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you reassign the value of the `v` parameter with `v = v.slice(1);`

Using another variable fixes the tsc compiler error :  `let vv; vv = v.slice(1);`

According to the [Type Guards specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#424-type-guards) no assignment to the variable or parameter are allowded :

> In the true branch statement of an 'if' statement, the type of a
>   variable or parameter is narrowed by a type guard in the 'if'
>   condition when true, provided no part of the 'if' statement contains
>   assignments to the variable or parameter

.

Comment: That doesn't address the errors in the (v instanceof BigNumber) block. There are the Property 's' does not exist on type 'string | number | BigNumber' errors. I have also added some code in the number block that results in an error without reassignment.

Comment: I don't get any error in any block as soon as I removed the reassignment in the "string" block

Comment: You're correct, I had another reassignment in the number block (not shown in the question), after removing it everything is compiling without error. It's interesting that a reassignment in one block results in type errors in all three blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain about the type (which in this case you are because of the type checking) you can pass a hint to the TypeScript compiler by using **[type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)** on the variables complaining:

```
...

else if( v === "string")
{
    // code dependent of v being a string
    if ((<string>v).charCodeAt(0) === 45)
    {
        v = (<string>v).slice(1);
        x.s = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        x.s = 1;
    }

    // Other stuff
}

...
```